# Calculate disk space occupied by many .png files

Tags: unix, shell, disk-space-utilization, find, scripting

I have 357 .png files located in different sub dirs of the current dir:

```
settings# find . -name \*.png |wc -l
    357

settings# find . -name \*.png | head
./assets/authenticationIcons/audio.png
./assets/authenticationIcons/bbid.png
./assets/authenticationIcons/camera.png
./bin/icons/ca_video_chat.png
./bin/icons/ca_voice_control.png
./bin/icons/ca_vpn.png
./bin/icons/ca_wifi.png
```

Is there a oneliner to calculate the total disk space occupied by them (before I pngcrush them)?

I've tried (unsuccessfully):

```
settings# find . -name \*.png | xargs du -s
4       ./assets/support/wifi_locked_icon_white.png
1       ./assets/support/wifi_vpn_icon_connected.png
1       ./assets/support/wi_fi.png
1       ./assets/support/wi_fi_conected.png
8       ./bin/blackberry-tablet-icon.png
2       ./bin/icons/ca_about.png
2       ./bin/icons/ca_accessibility.png
2       ./bin/icons/ca_accounts.png
2       ./bin/icons/ca_airplane_mode.png
2       ./bin/icons/ca_application_permissions.png
1       ./bin/icons/ca_balance.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

`find . -type f -name "*.png" -printf '%s\n' | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'`

? Seems to work for me - results would be in bytes.

Comment: This is quite expensive, since du (an external command) is executed once for every file.

Comment: No need to pipe to `cut -f1`.

Comment: @quanta: Doh, you're right :)

Comment: @adaptr A new approach vs. du - as I agree, but he said he didn't have many files so I figured efficiency wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

`du` is my favorite answer.  If you have a fixed filesystem structure, you can use:

```
du -hc *.png
```

If you need to add subdirs, just add:

```
du -hc *.png **/*.png **/**/*.png
```

etc etc

However, this isn't a very useful command, so using your find:

```
TOTAL=0;for I in $(find . -name \*.png); do  TOTAL=$((TOTAL+$(du $I | awk '{print $1}'))); done; echo $TOTAL
```

That will echo the total size in bytes of all of the files you find.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

To find the size in Kbytes (as long as column 5 of ls -l is 'size'

```
find . -name \*.png -exec ls -lk {} \; | awk '{ sum +=$5} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: DO NOT try to parse the output of ls! It *represents* filesystem content, it is not actual filesystem content.

Comment: Yet we dont need to measure the filesystem content, we need to just sum the representation.

Comment: That's where the difference lies between the output from ls and du.

Answer (score -1):

`find . -name *.png -print0 | du -c --files0-from=- | tail -1`

In logical block sizes; insert -b in the du command to output bytes.

Comment: Lack of the quotes around the file name.

Comment: Irrelevant when using NUL-terminated filenames.

Comment: Don't you get `find: paths must precede expression...`?

Comment: Only if you typo'ed my solution.

Comment: Do you want to see a screenshot?

Comment: Some linux will give that error if you lack quotes around file names with wildcards.

Comment: I suspect that in that case it will depend on the version of find or bash - not Linux.